# My mother benefits from riba-based income. My father has a second marriage. Is this halal?

Tags: riba

Aoa.

My father has a second marriage and due to his job posting, is living in another country with his second wife.

Me and my sisters are from the first marriage. My father earns good income and covers about 70-80% of our expenditure including bills and education.

My mother has some inheritance money from her father’s death which she keeps in the bank and gets monthly interest on.

My father’s contribution to the household is handsome but isn’t enough to support the lifestyle me, my mother and my sisters are accustomed to (May Allah protect me from being ungrateful.

The car my family travels in, the fuel costs, some food costs and servant salaries come from my mother’s riba-based income.

I am 20 and I’m trying to make a living through freelancing but I’m not established yet.

Upon learning just how deep the ramifications and sin of riba is, I have told my mother to stop. She has enough money in the bank to support us for 2 months comfortably, and a real estate deal that will bring us good money is in the works.

I’ve advised my mother to put her Tawakkul in Allah and stop consuming risk and In Sha Allah, Allah will provide rizq and baraqa soon through the real estate deal.

She claims that since she cant earn and her husband doesnt support her financially and doesnt have a father, it is excused for her.

I have consulted my father too and he also doesn’t think there’s anything wrong with this.

I am fearful that my family’s consumption of riba might stop us from securing that deal, stop us from receiving baraqa in rizq and hurt me in my career (May Allah have mercy on us)

What should one do in a situation like this?